# Is there way to convert web application in python flask to mobile?

Tags: python, web, flask, mobile

I know that there are ways to convert web site to mobile application using directories and platforms, but it seems like all the examples were on JavaScript. Does it also work with python flask web application?

Answer (score 0):

You won’t be able to convert python django application into a native mobile application.

For web application, both the client side and server side code is rendered through web browser. For mobile, client side code sits in native inside the mobile and all the dynamic stuff gets loaded from server through http/https. Python django app is generally written in MVT format, UI is closely tied with server side backend code.

To convert your present app into mobile app requires:

Implement django rest framework to write rest apis
A native mobile app which can consume those apis (this is full mobile app development)
Workarounds:

There is a way where you write a small mobile app which loads your website. This can be done but only requirement is your site needs to be responsive UI and compatible on mobile browser